# Unable to find application on Google Play (Mobile and Tablet devices)

Tags: android, google-play

Recently I've updated one of my android application on 24th June, 2016. Before that it was all working fine and expected. I was able to search application on every device including mobiles,tablets and web platform.

It also went well for 2-3 days after I updated on 24th June,2016. But yesterday I found that application is not searchable on mobiles and tablets, however I'm able to search the same app on web platform.

I've double check the mainfest config and it has nothing to do with this as I've following code in mainfest to support all the devices, and app doesn't require any mandatory feature of devices which should filter mobiles or tablets. (*Mainfest was not changed in last update though so Mainfest config is not the issue*)

```
<supports-screens
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Strange thing is I'm able to search it on web platform and it shows '*Compatible with your devices*', and when I click on install it gets installed on my mobile device through web. (No errors or warning at all)

Another strange thing I found is when I go to **My Apps** section of mobile playstore, app is there in the list and it gets open on click. It just doesn't get searched.

Comment: I've noticed the same exact thing for some apps starting on 2016-06-29. They show up on desktop but not on mobile or tablets for searches or for "More by [Developer]" lists, but no recent updates to the apps were made. Maybe it's a country specific thing, what country are you from?

Comment: I'm from India, and app is only available to India.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Application is now searchable on both mobile and tablet devices.
 Don't know what the actual problem was, I have changed some code in application and updated the APK in production.

Now it is searchable in every devices, I've updated the APK yesterday and it's searchable from today.
 So it took a day to get it searched. May be there was some issue in Google search indexing, still not sure what was the problem.

It's confirmed there was some problem from Google's end. Here is what I got in email today,

> Thanks for contacting Google Play Developer Support and checking in on
>   this issue.
>
> I appreciate your patience while our team investigates the behavior
>   you experienced.
>
> I checked in with our team and they’ve recently made some changes that
>   should fix the problem. With the recent set of changes, please check
>   to see if you’re still experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I talked with the developer support and explained the problem with the screenshot and they responded yesterday that their message

> Hi,
>
> Thanks for clarifying.
>
> I’ve documented your issue and escalated it to our technical team for
>   further investigation. Our team is working to resolve this issue for
>   you as soon as possible.
>
> I appreciate your patience and I’ll let you know the moment I have an
>   update.
>
> If you have any other questions in the meantime, please let me know.

Today, I have a problem is resolved without updating the application

The problem they have and there is no problem in our applications

Comment: That's true, I'd same response too and got it resolved.